# Editando o formulário de configurações de cursos

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, moodle

Estou editando o formulário de configurações de cursos no `moodle` e ele funciona, ele adicionou o campo mas não salva, se eu mudar no `banco de dados` os dados salvos são impressos no `input`, só que não salva.

**edit_form.php**

```
    $mform->addElement('text', 'hora', 'Hora do Curso', 'maxlength="100" size="20"');
    $mform->setType('hora', PARAM_TEXT);
    if (!empty($course->id)) {
        $mform->setConstant('hora', $course->hora);
    }

    $mform->addElement('text', 'local', 'Local do Curso', 'maxlength="100" size="20"');
    $mform->setType('local', PARAM_TEXT);
    if (!empty($course->id)) {
        $mform->setConstant('local', $course->local);
    }
```

Preciso editar outros arquivos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver editando o arquivo `edit.php`, inclui algumas linhas no código para adicionar valores ao objeto $data, exemplo:

```
$data->hora = $_POST["hora"];
$data->local = $_POST["local"];
```

Lembrando que na tabela de cursos criei o campo `hora` e `local` e adicionei os campos do curso no formulário como informado na pergunta.